# Sencha touch 2: map marker titles

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch, extjs, google-maps-markers, sencha-touch-2

I can add markers to maps, and the marker pin appears ok, but I don't see any titles on them!

I loop through my store and add them like this:

```
           //plot the points on the map
           for (var i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++)
           {                 
               var position = new google.maps.LatLng(this.getAt(i).data.Latitude, this.getAt(i).data.Longitude); 
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                   title : this.getAt(i).data.LocationDesc,
                   map: Ext.ComponentManager.get('jobmap').getMap()
               });
           }
```

I see pins, but no text title! The data is ok, and I've even tried hard coded strings. Is there some kind of overlay/mask property? How do I get the titles to appear?

**EDIT**: Below solution solves the issue, but I also thought I'd throw in the solutions to related problems I had.

If you want to place popup info windows on multiple markers you need to read this: [Trying to bind multiple InfoWindows to multiple Markers on a Google Map and failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357323/trying-to-bind-multiple-infowindows-to-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-and-fail)

The infoWindows will be blank until you make the font non-white! [Google Maps API InfoWindow not Displaying content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290001/google-maps-api-infowindow-not-displaying-content)

Comment: What do you mean by titles? Do you mean to open some window showing it's address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [MarkerOptions Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions),
`title` property of `marker` is seen as a `rollover` text.

I wonder, how it can be seen on `smartphone` devices, where there's no event like `mouseover`?

I think you'll need to open some `infoWindow` on `click` those `pins/markers` on map.

You can do it like this,

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content:'_address_' }),
```

and then listen for the click event on the marker,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Comment: will fail on multiple bindings, you need to wrap the listener